# Why is there excess space at the bottom of my website?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am in the process of trying to teach myself to build responsive websites. I am utilizing Zurb's Foundation 6 and have actually managed to put together a simple website, but I am having a problem with spacing at the bottom of the page.

The problem area is with the "pagination" and "footer" sections of my page.

The site can be seen at test.allvixen.com and my code looks like:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
    <center>
            <nav class="pagination">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">&laquo; First</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">&lsaquo; Back</a></li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">8</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">9</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">10</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">11</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">12</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">13</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">14</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">15</a></li>
                <li> . . . </li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">94</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">95</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">96</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">Next &rsaquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">Last &raquo;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="large-12 columns">
  <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2013 - <a href="http://allvixen.com/">allvixen.com</a>
        </div>
        </center>

        </div>
```

I cannot figure out how to reduce or close the gap between the page pagination and the copyright notice. I also cannot figure out why I have so much space below the copyright notice.

Can someone be so kind as to offer some advice as to what I did wrong or where I can learn more about this specific problem and how to correct it?

Comment: create a fiddler or running sample for it...

Answer (score 0):

The `columns` class has a min height of `350px`. This is causing your last columns element to be larger than it should be.

For `columns` that you do not want to have a min height, put `min-height:0px;`.

Example:

```
.columns:last-child {
  min-height:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Your suggestion fixed the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

center tag  Must be in the right place. Also http://test.allvixen.com/  has app.css with columns class that it has min-height:350px. Delete min-height.

```html
    <center>

<div class="large-12 columns">
            <nav class="pagination">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">&laquo; First</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">&lsaquo; Back</a></li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">8</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">9</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">10</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">11</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">12</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">13</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">14</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">15</a></li>
                <li> . . . </li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">94</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">95</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">96</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">Next &rsaquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="" rel="nofollow">Last &raquo;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="large-12 columns">
  <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2013 - <a href="http://allvixen.com/">allvixen.com</a>
        </div>

        </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I am not sure that I understand "center tag Must be in the right place."  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: <center> </center> must be out of div in your code.

Comment: Thank you. Had a senior moment.   LOL

Comment: @Vance Please accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.